# Odoo: how to edit invoice / quote layout CSS

Tags: css, odoo

We are building an Odoo 13 EE / CE installation and would like to make small changes for PDF quotations and invoices. There are small problems that would be pretty simple to fix with editing CSS file. Those are:

- Increasing the size of the customer logo (upper left hand corner)
- Reducing the font size of sender name and address as they overfow to
  multiple lines
- Fixing the too small text area where recipient name
  and address are. Modify its location at the middle right hand corner
  (above the Quotation #S000003)
- Adding a style for generic terms and
  conditions (small print)

From `Settings` -> `General` -> `Business Documents` -> `Layout`, We can see that this PDF is using `external_layout_standard` QView and we can access the XML architecture of this report. However, editing this view as an Odoo admin does not allow access to CSS files where we would be able to modify `<DIV class>` attributes like font size and element size.

This server is hosted on Odoo.sh platform, so **we do not have an access to the file system**. Our options are either to modify the system parameters or create a totally new extension. The latter seems a bit overkill because the changes are so small and we actually would need to go and modify all Odoo-generated PDFs like quotations, order confirmations, purchase orders, repair orders etc. etc.

So, can anyone advice what is the correct approach of modifying these Odoo-generated PDFs and how to access their CSS?

Screen captures illustrating the problem:

https://snipboard.io/9UYmBd.jpg

[image]
https://snipboard.io/8pIjB9.jpg

[image]

Comment: Add inline CSS if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Ex4 for the idea. The quick & dirty solution is exactly to add a style attribute for DIV sections. This is hardly the ideal solution, but resolves the inmediate problem.

To apply the QnD-solution, follow the steps:

1. `Settings` with Developer mode on -> `Edit document layout` under Business documents
2. Look for section

```
<div class="col-6" name="company_address">
    <div t-field="company.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>
</div>
```

Add Style attribute (`style="font-size:14px"`) for inner `<div>`:

```
<div class="col-6" name="company_address">
    <div t-field="company.partner_id" style="font-size:14px" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>
</div>
```

3. This changes the sender company address font size. We do still need to change the recipient address font size.
4. Navigate to `Settings` -> `Technical` -> `Views` (under User interface)
5. Search for `address_layout`
6. Add same style attbute (`style="font-size:14px"`) for section:

```
<div style="font-size:14px" name="address" t-att-class="colclass">
    <t t-raw="address"/>
</div>
```

The end result is not the prettiest layout in the world, but it works:
https://snipboard.io/oDicR7.jpg

The right way is apparently to inherit 'account.report_invoice_document' and then change the template code. So this is not possible with only Odoo admin UI. It requires writing a small extension.

Comment: You're not right on your last part. `account.report_invoice_document` is a record of `ir.ui.view` and therefor inheritable under Settings/Technical/...Views. You're able to create `ir.ui.view` records there, which can be related (inheriting) to another view. This QnD solution has one really big problem: after update of the module it is coming from or other modules, which will then update this module (account), your changes will be gone, EXCEPT you change the `ir.model.data` (external ID) entry for `account.report_invoice_document` and set "Non Updatable" to true.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem and with thanks to Ossi Mantylahti who pointed me to this thread I have managed to change the address format also both purchase order and RFQ pdf documents to make them more acceptable

Modify this file for purchase orders 
Technical -> Views -> report_purchaseorder_document
Locate the section

Request for Quotation #

```
        <h4 t-if="o.state in ['sent', 'to approve']">Purchase Order #<span t-field="o.name"/></h4>
        <h4 t-if="o.state in ['purchase', 'done']">Purchase Order #<span t-field="o.name"/></h4>
        <h4 t-if="o.state == 'cancel'">Cancelled Purchase Order #<span t-field="o.name"/></h4>
```

For RFQ modify
views -> report_purchasequotation_document
 Request for Quotation

Note these header tags were h2's

Answer (score 0):

As a quick 'n dirty solution, could you just give `style` attribute to a element.

As far as I know you cannot modify CSS from user interface. You have to create a custom module and install it instead.